# How to add datasource on Query Promt Invoice?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need to insert an another datasource on *Query promt* [image: InvoiceQuery].

I saw there is a class **SalesFormletterParmData** and **SalesFormletterParmDataInvoice** but if I insert in method `SalesFormletterParmDataInvoice\updateQueryBuild`

```
qbds = chooseLines.query().addDataSource(tableNum(CustPackingSlipJour));
qbr = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(CustPackingSlipJour, PackingSlipId));
```

But not filder anything.
I want to have the data source added in query everytime loollike this, but bu code:

[image]

there is a way ?

Thanks.

Comment: tag _jquery_? or _query_ _sql_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to add a datasource to the top level of the query:

```
qbds = chooseLines.query().addDataSource(tableNum(CustPackingSlipJour));
```

Modify your code as following:

```
qbds = chooseLines.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesTable)).addDataSource(tableNum(CustPackingSlipJour));
qdbs.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
qbds.relations(true);
qbr = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(CustPackingSlipJour, PackingSlipId));
```

This will give the expected result

[image]

Please take into account that in standard AX if you set *Quantity* to *Delivery note* in parameters you will be able to choose Delivery notes in new window, or add query criteria using *Select* button

[image]

Comment: hi @Aliaksandr Maksimau thanks for helm , but not work again.

Comment: There is another way ? or another method to use?

Comment: I saw the Table CustPackingSlipJour, But not filder by value insered in Query Promt.

Comment: Try adding a `qdbs.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);`